# The cursor focus stays on the Editor and does not switch to Console when I try to get the an input from the user in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My main method intends to take a string from the user and print it.
However, **I can only enter the input string when I manually click on the Console window**.
Otherwise, the string I type gets typed in the Editor window.

Can we switch the cursor focus automatically on console when an input is expected from the user?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = new String();
    System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
    name = br.readLine();   
    System.out.println(name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse IDE has different parts(views) : Editor, Package Explorer, Outline, Console etc. Each time one part is active. When you have an active part, all keyboard input will be going to that part.
Ofcourse, if you want to write on console, you need to make the console active.